# Using definition, prove that the following limit exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**Definition**. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let $I$ be an open interval which contains $a$, and let $f$ be a real function defined everywhere on $I$ except possibly at $a$. Then $f(x)$ is said to be converge to $L$, as $x$ approaches $a$, if and only if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$0 < \left| x-a\right| < \delta$ implies $\left| f\left( x\right) -L\right| < \varepsilon$.

Prove that $\lim _{x\rightarrow 2}x^{2}+2x-5=3$.

In the my proof, I chose $\delta=$min{$1,\varepsilon/7$}. **Can you check?**

Comment: @SalahFatima Yes. Edited.

Comment: Yes, that choice of $\delta$ works.

Comment: Can we check what? If that choice of delta is appropriate? Why don't you include your derivation of that delta, or where in the correctness proof you get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$|f(x)-3|=|x^2+2x-8|=|x+4||x-2|.$$

Thus, if $\delta\le 1$ then $1\le x\le 3.$ Thus $5\le x+4\le 7$ and $$|f(x)-3|\le 7\delta.$$ So if you consider $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/7\}$ you are done.

Comment: I didn't consider $\delta=$min{$1,\varepsilon/5$}. How did you think to consider the $\delta$?

Comment: @Arthur How can you say $\left| f\left( x\right) -3\right| \leq 5\delta$. Why '5'? Can you explain clearly?

Comment: @Kahler You're right. It was my mistake. $|x-2|\le 1$ doesn't imply $|x+4|\le 5.$ The bound we have is $|x+4|\le 7.$ This justifies the choose $\epsilon/7.$

Comment: @Kahler I didn't look too closely at the calculations, sorry.

Comment: @Arthur Okey. So, can I say that if $\delta\geq 1$ and $\left| x-2\right| < \delta$ then $-\delta < x-2 < \delta$, $6-\delta < x+4 < \delta +6\geq 7$. Hence, $(x+4)$ is bounded. I.e., $\left| x+4\right| < 7$ ?

Comment: @Kahler Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^2+2x-5$ then

$$f(x)-3=x^2-4+2x-4=(x-2)(x+2)+2(x-2)$$

$$\implies |f(x)-3|=|x+4| |x-2|$$.

As $x$ is in a neigborhood of $2$, we can add the condition

$|x-2|<\color{red}{1} $ or $1<x<3.$

then

$5<x+4<7$ and $|f(x)-3|<7|x-2|$.

So, for given $\epsilon>0$, if we take

$$\eta=\min(\color{red}{1},\frac{\epsilon}{7}),$$

we will have

$$|x-2|<\eta\implies $$

$|x-2|<1 $ and  $|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{7} $
$\implies |x+4|<7$ and $ |x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$

$$\implies |f(x)-3|<\epsilon$$

$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=3.$$

Comment: If you change the red one, you won't get  7.